# iReport Error evaluating expression

Tags: java, xml, ireport

We're using iReport 5.0.1, and have successfully converted many of our Crystal Reports packages over.

I'm working with data that is a mixture of integer and double data type, and I am performing calculations inside the variable fields in the detail section.

I then have 3 variables that are summing the detail data.  The first variable is a straight sum of the detail variable above it.  The second one adds either one Parameter, or a second Parameter, depending on an IF..THEN..ELSE statement, and the third subtracts the very same Parameter values based on a similar IF..THEN..ELSE statement.

I need to round the 3 variable fields in the Group Footer, so I apply Math.round(variable_name) to each of the 3 variables.  The original one, and the last one (subtracting the Parameters) both work perfectly.  The middle variable (adding the Parameters) throws an error, "Error evaluating expression: Math.round(variable_name)".  If I take out the formatting, it runs fine.

I have copied and pasted the working variables, renaming it to the correct name, to make sure that I'm not missing something in the way I set them up originally, to no avail.  When I run it using Empty Datasource, it runs, but of course with no data.

This would lead me to believe that there is a problem with the data, but I've checked it throughout and the data is all valid for the data sources, no NULL, blank or character data.

I'm pretty stumped at this point.  The report compiles and runs just fine in Crystal Reports, using pretty close to the same functions.

If anyone has any recommendations, I'm happy to listen, and I am posting the XML of the report below.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can offer.

M. Snyder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports         http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MarginRequirement"         language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20"         rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="70f7c2ab-dba2-420a-98b9-        dc041beb65a7">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit"         value="/reports/Risk_Management/MarginRequirement"/>
        <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url"         value="http://reports.beefnw.com/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
<parameter name="LCF" class="java.lang.Float">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="LCO" class="java.lang.Float">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="FCF" class="java.lang.Float">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0.00]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="FCO" class="java.lang.Float">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="GF" class="java.lang.Float">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="GO" class="java.lang.Float">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select *,
    if (mid(symbol,-3,1) in("F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "Q", "U", "V", "X", "Z"),         "Future", "Option") AS type from margin_requirements
    order by location, clearing_house
    ]]>
</queryString>
<field name="open_price" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="equity" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="close_price" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="open_total_value" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="close_total_value" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="liquidating_value" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="commission" class="java.lang.Float">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="account_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="position_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="contract_weight" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="contracts" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="account_name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="account_number" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="location" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="clearing_house" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="type" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="group" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="symbol" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="fill_date" class="java.sql.Date">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="updated_at" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="created_at" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="loc_clHouse" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{location} + " - " + $F{clearing_house}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LC_Orig" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{group}=="LIVE_CATTLE"?((($F{contracts}*$F{contract_weight}*$F{open_price})/100)*-1) + (($F{contracts}*$F{contract_weight}*$F{close_price})/100):0.0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LCOrig_Total" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="Group" resetGroup="ClearingHouse" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Math.round($V{LC_Orig})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="Suppression" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA["NO"]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LCUpPrice" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{type}=="Future"?$F{close_price}+$P{LCF}:$F{close_price}+$P{LCO}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LCDownPrice" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{type}=="Future"?$F{close_price}-$P{LCF}:$P{LCO} > $F{close_price}?0.0:$F{close_price}-$P{LCO}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LC_Decrease" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{group}=="LIVE_CATTLE"?((($F{contracts}*$F{contract_weight}*$F{open_price})/100)*-1)+(($F{contracts}*$F{contract_weight}*$V{LCDownPrice})/100):0.0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LCDecr_Total" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="Group" resetGroup="ClearingHouse" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Math.round($V{LC_Decrease})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LCIncr_Total" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="Group" resetGroup="ClearingHouse" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Math.round($V{LC_Increase})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="LC_Increase" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{group}=="LIVE_CATTLE"?((($F{contracts}*$F{contract_weight}*$F{open_price})/100)*-1)+(($F{contracts}*$F{contract_weight}*$V{LCUpPrice})/100):0.0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<group name="ClearingHouse">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{loc_clHouse}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="25">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{Suppression}=="YES"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="51b78c4d-3747-4282-8b9f-17be6f84feea" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{loc_clHouse}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ad970881-452b-42aa-bb9f-a19e735643c5" x="179" y="5" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Suppression}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="116">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="79587964-7211-4761-9221-0c063a1aebf0" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{loc_clHouse}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement uuid="3bd9ce71-5cf4-4ae3-b678-8f3942fc9e7a" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LCOrig_Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement uuid="20ef4729-88b0-4ab2-a5a6-56594bb716d5" x="100" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LCDecr_Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="16a8b6f9-5e24-4ee6-9e84-e2730d78dea1" x="100" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LCIncr_Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="142" splitType="Stretch">
        <image>
            <reportElement uuid="eef5e5ab-7b5d-4f86-a20f-5dd51bbd56bd" x="5" y="4" width="310" height="93"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/marlin/bnw_logo_trans.gif"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="957ac037-7238-46e1-809c-4ded5f76b72b" x="0" y="102" width="572" height="38" forecolor="#E6D8AB" backcolor="#E6D8AB"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="3b2925af-f556-4c0c-84bb-e5b5b021128e" x="126" y="110" width="341" height="30"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[MARGIN REQUIREMENT REPORT]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="a2f2bf6a-6f14-48e5-9d19-5f153caed5a5" x="0" y="0" width="572" height="27" forecolor="#E6D8AB" backcolor="#E6D8AB"/>
        </rectangle>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="96" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{Suppression}=="NO"]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ed06c6f7-7b44-4033-8c4a-9364d9c22e13" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LC_Orig}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="55b4791f-dfe7-415c-89d5-ebd937c6a329" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Suppression}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="aba93e69-1ab0-476a-81e0-c65d8f482233" x="100" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LC_Decrease}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="6f9026a6-abf5-4017-974c-9e972bed8181" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{LCF}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ff53c29d-4006-4b99-8b77-295717483c79" x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{LCO}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="e305cdbe-e93c-47bb-aedd-f2fc1478e33d" x="100" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LC_Increase}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the iReport/Jasper forums for the answer:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/803533/ireport-error-evaluating-expression#comment-802119

M. Snyder